# How to Setup Reverse DNS On Linode for Your Instance when you use Cloudflare to Provide DNS

Tags: server, dns, cloudflare, linode

Hi Our site is based on [Smartphone, Laptop, Gadgets Specs, Price](https://www.pdevice.com/)

and we are using Linode server to get host our site but same sit opening in Linode rDNS, due to this most of our links such as https://www.pdevice.com/product/samsung-galaxy-s20-ultra-5g-price-specs opening with Linode domain address, we also contacted to them they have told us that, It looks like "pdevice.com" is your domain name but since it's pointing to CloudFlare's IP, you would need a work around in regards to setting reverse DNS. An option would be to create a subdomain and point this to your server's IP address. You may be able to get around this by having the "www" record for your domain point to your server's IP addresses rather than Cloudflare's IP addresses. and as we told we are using Cloudflare to provide CDN and DNS so how to solve this isse we can't recognize, because it shows issue while past RDNS to Subdomain.pdevice dot com, so how to do this with our server.